# RStudio JavaScript Schema Error on opening and when selecting Global Options

Tags: javascript, r, rstudio

RStudio Edition :  Desktop
RStudio Version :  2023.09
OS Version      :  Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit), macOS Monterey 12.7
R Version       :  4.3.2 (2023-10-31)

I believe this started when I attempted to render a very large mapview object. RStudio crashed and then when I tried to re-open the application, this error popped up.

`Uncaught Exception: Error: Config schema violation: view/zoomLevel must be >= 0.25 at e.exports._validate (/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app-x64/.webpack/main/index.js:8:50391) at set store [as store] (/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app-x64/.webpack/main/index.js:8:49350) at e.exports.set (/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app-x64/.webpack/main/index.js:8:48118) at D.zoomLevel (/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app-x64/.webpack/main/index.js:19:52659) at IpcMainImpl.<anonymous> (/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app-x64/.webpack/main/index.js:19:20524) at IpcMainImpl.emit (node:events:513:28) at WebContents.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:90214) at WebContents.emit (node:events:513:28)`

Once I click OK about 3 times, RStudio proceeds to load. Then when I go to Tools -> Global Options, the error pops up again, and RStudio freezes.

I've troubleshooted this with several different versions of RStudio and R, resetting the desktop state and removing all .Rdata, .Renviron, and .Rsession files. [This error](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11984) from about a year ago seemed to be the closest to what I'm experiencing, but even after cleaning up all the files, using App Cleaner and re-installing RStudio and R, the problem persists. I believe the error might be a corrupt .plist file, but I'm unsure how to approach this to make RStudio function normally without the error popping up.

Comment: It seems like you should open your own issue in the RStudio github https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues or post in the RStudio community site: https://community.rstudio.com/. Those seem like much better places to get help for an IDE specific error.